# Increase cell reference when dragging down

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am having a real hard time figuring out how I can just simply drag a cell reference from another sheet and make it increase by "9", so for example I want the following to happen when I drag down the formula:

```
=!DataA1
=!DataA10
=!DataA19
=!DataA28
```

etc..

I have searched around but I have yet to find a working solution, anyone can give me a helping hand?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `INDEX` function:

```
=INDEX(Data!A:A,(ROW()-1)*9+1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, and if I would want to begin from column 4 from the other sheet and then count down 9, how would I go about doing that with the formula I did some attempts my self but I just got a "#NAME"? error.

Comment: @MatsEriksson Try replace semicolon with comma in my formula.

Comment: @MatsEriksson Start from 4th column? Then change ```Data!A:A``` to ```Data!D:D```.

Comment: I am sorry, I meant ROW. If, I want to start from A4 for example how would I go about doing that?

Comment: @MatsEriksson use ```=INDEX($A$4:$A$1000,(ROW()-1)*9+1)```.

Comment: Sorry, for all the questions but I am really bad at these excel calculations. That doesn't seem to be applicable if it is in another sheet such as in the examples you mentioned before?

Comment: @MatsEriksson can you share your sample workbook in OneDrive or GoogleSheets? And post link here.